Issues using match to replace values - "Can't use NA as column index in a tibble for assignment"
I have a dataframe of with a column of NA's. I need to replace these NAs with the values from another table. This is a relatively straightforward problem and has been addressed here: Replace NAs in one DF with values from another DF
I boiled it down to a very simple reprex and get the error:
Error in `[<-`:
! Can't use NA as column index in a tibble for assignment.
Backtrace:
 1. base::`[<-`(...)
 2. tibble:::`[<-.tbl_df`(...)

Reprex:
# This is the data with NAs that need to be replaced
to_be_replaced <- structure(list(id = c("20", "21", "22", "23"
), df = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), factor = c("a", 
"a", "a", "a")), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))

# These are the replacement data
to_insert <- structure(list(id = structure(20:23, levels = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", 
"9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24"), class = "factor"), df_min = c(1000, 1450, NA, NA
), df = c(60000, 90000, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))

Here's my attempt to use match
to_be_replaced[match(to_insert$id, to_be_replaced$id), match(names(to_insert), names(to_be_replaced))] <- to_insert

Error in `[<-`(`*tmp*`, match(to_insert$id, to_be_replaced$id), match(names(to_insert),  :
9.
stop(fallback)
8.
signal_abort(cnd, .file)
7.
abort(x, class, ..., call = call, parent = parent, use_cli_format = TRUE)
6.
tibble_abort(call = call, "Can't use NA as column index in a tibble for assignment.")
5.
abort_assign_columns_non_na_only(call)
4.
vectbl_as_new_col_index(j, xo, j_arg, names2(value), value_arg,
call = call)
3.
tbl_subassign(x, i, j, value, i_arg, j_arg, substitute(value))
2.
`[<-.tbl_df`(`*tmp*`, match(to_insert$id, to_be_replaced$id),
match(names(to_insert), names(to_be_replaced)), value = structure(list(
id = c("20", "21", "22", "23"), df_min = c(1000, 1450,
NA, NA), df = c(60000, 90000, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, ...
1.
`[<-`(`*tmp*`, match(to_insert$id, to_be_replaced$id), match(names(to_insert),
names(to_be_replaced)), value = structure(list(id = c("20",
"21", "22", "23"), df_min = c(1000, 1450, NA, NA), df = c(60000,
90000, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c("tbl_df", ...


I have also attempted using replace with mixed results
# This doesn't work
to_be_replaced |>
  mutate(df = replace(df, id == "20" | id == "21", to_insert[,"df"]))

# A tibble: 4 × 3
  id    df        factor
  <chr> <list>    <chr> 
1 20    <dbl [4]> a     
2 21    <dbl [4]> a     
3 22    <dbl [1]> a     
4 23    <dbl [1]> a     

# This works but throws an error?
to_be_replaced |>
  mutate(df = replace(df, id == "20" | id == "21", to_insert$df))

# A tibble: 4 × 3
  id       df factor
  <chr> <dbl> <chr> 
1 20    60000 a     
2 21    90000 a     
3 22       NA a     
4 23       NA a     

Warning: There was 1 warning in `mutate()`.
ℹ In argument: `df = replace(df, id == "20" | id == "21", to_insert$df)`.
Caused by warning in `x[list] <- values`:
! number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length


Maybe transform(to_be_replaced, df = to_insert$df[match(id, to_insert$id)]).

match(names(to_insert), names(to_be_replaced)) gives an NA. As the error says, you can't have an NA as an index for a column when doing a replacement.
Find a different way of matching the names between both datasets, like intersect:
cv <- intersect(names(to_be_replaced), names(to_insert))
rv <- match(to_insert$id, to_be_replaced$id)
to_be_replaced[rv, cv] <- to_insert[cv]
to_be_replaced
#  id    df factor
#1 20 60000      a
#2 21 90000      a
#3 22    NA      a
#4 23    NA      a


Or you might use rows_update from dplyr:
to_be_replaced |>
  rows_update(to_insert |> select(id, df))

Result
  id       df factor
  <chr> <dbl> <chr> 
1 20    60000 a     
2 21    90000 a     
3 22       NA a     
4 23       NA a   

